# How to prevent multiple users from simultaneously accessing an Azure VM?

Tags: windows, remote-access, azure-vm

We created a VM as a replacement for physical machine with rarely used software on it.

When I tested it I noticed when a second user accesses the VM, the first user is kicked out and sees the message **"You have been disconnected because another connection was made to the remote computer"**.
However, on another VM that wasn't set up by me, I'm getting the warning **"Another user is signed in. If you continue, they’ll be disconnected. Do you want to sign in any way?"**

What VM or Windows setting(s) do I need to change to display this message on the new VM?

Comment: The message pair is for opposite actions. The first message is for when you log in first. The second message is for when someone else is logged in first. Both VMs are set up the same in regards to RDP action. You do not want to disable another user logging in. You can get yourself locked out of the system, forcing you to reboot the system to recover.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain the problem correctly. I want the VM to display "Another user is signed in. If you continue, they’ll be disconnected. Do you want to sign in any way?", but I don't know what setting controls this message. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following answer on [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/a/1079259/847128) more helpful than the "copy & paste reply" by Jabbar.

Answer (score -1):

The message you want will appear for the 3rd user on Windows server:

> By default a Windows VM in Azure is configured for remote administration, which allows up to 2 users to access the machine to undertake remote administration of that machine. If a third user attempts to connect you will see this message. you will see this if a user has disconnected, but not logged off so their session is till running and using a slot.

> Windows Server will, by default, let 2 concurrent users log on. Windows 10, will only allow only 1 user.

Comment: `**Windows Server** will, by default, let 2 concurrent users log on.` I clearly stated that I'm having problems limiting access to a **Azure VM** not **Windows Server**.  `By default a Windows VM in Azure is configured for remote administration, which allows up to 2 users to access the machine to undertake remote administration of that machine.` If that were the case I wouldn't have asked the question.

Comment: @Nemo "a Windows VM" = "Azure VM running windows", I think you did not understand my answer. if you have more info then update your question. anyway I don't think your question is suitable here, you should send it to Microsoft support team.